# I want to build a android system that default input method is not Android keyboard

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-input-method

When I build a android system and I start it first time, the default input method is Android keyboard(AOSP).

Can I change that Android keyboard input method to Japanese IME by changing some code (my system is jelly bean)?

Answer (score -1):

i have solved this problem .add a string in defaults.xml.andd loadSecureSetting(,) in DatabaseHelper.java(this method you can be searched by google).note:the unique identifier of the input method must be correct.ive make a mistake on that.

Comment: can you mention what you write in default.xml please?